# php, jquery, how to trigger a click?

Tags: php, jquery

i have a link that needs to be triggered from a success post:

```
<?php    
if ($_POST["action"] == "1") {
?>
<script type='text/javascript'> 
$(window).load(function() {
    $(".likepic").click();
});
</script>
<?php } ?>

<script type='text/javascript'> 
$(window).load(function() {
$(".likepic").click(function(){
    $(".likepic").colorbox({width:"620px", height:"570px", inline:true, href:"#likepic_lightbox"});
});
});
</script>
<a href="#" class="likepic"></a>
<div class="blackk" style="display:none;">
<div id="likepic_lightbox">test
</div>
</div>
```

so if that `post` action is `1` then run the jquery script and `click` on the link for something else to happen :)

this is what i tried but without success.

any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `$(document).ready()` instead of `$(window).load()`

Also, you'll need to switch the order of your JavaScript blocks. The click handler needs to be defined first.

Play with a test version here: http://jsfiddle.net/irama/bcMp7/

Or see updated code below:

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".likepic").click(function(){
            $(".likepic").colorbox({width:"620px", height:"570px", inline:true, href:"#likepic_lightbox"});
        });
    });
</script>

<?php if ($_POST["action"] == "1") { ?>
<script type='text/javascript'> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".likepic").click();
    });
</script>
<?php } ?>


<a href="#" class="likepic"></a>
<div class="blackk" style="display:none;">
    <div id="likepic_lightbox">test</div>
</div>
```

Let us know how you go!

Comment: i didn't manage to make it work yet, though it seems that should

Comment: What's the issue that you're facing now? Any errors in the JS console? Any PHP errors?

Comment: no, the script doesn't run, there should be that lightbox popping up... hmmm

Comment: Hi @Patrioticcow that sounds like it might be a different issue related to the lightbox (not related to PHP triggering a click event). If you replace the colorbox call with an alert('test') and it pops up, then this question has been answered. Happy to help work through the other issue, but its probably best to start a new question for it.

Comment: Hi @Patrioticcow - How'd you go? Let us know if you need any more help with this question. I'm not too familiar with colorbox, but I'm happy to take a look.

Comment: looks like i had a duplicate script, when i remove it and left only one call to the colorbox script it start working, off course using your code. Thanks

Comment: Sweet! No worries, happy to help.